# I want to make command that detects online members form a specific role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I need help with

```
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined"
```

So basically I am trying to make a command that detects the online members with a specific role but when I want to filter the fetch I get this Error.

```js
if (command === 't') {
        let guild = bot.guilds.cache.get('750637822343512085');
        let collection = guild.members.fetch()
        collection.filter(guild.members.roles.cache.has("837754186048208907")).then(console.log)
    }
```

and if you could give me a way of showing the online members with the specific role I would be so grateful.

**(NOTE: the code is not completed I am stuck with filtering the Roles only)**

Comment: Is this in a module file? Or your index.js? If it is in a module, make sure your execution parameters are in the right order. `bot` is defined but `bot.guilds` is not defined which means `bot` isn't an instance of `Client`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve this you will need to get the [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild), then a [`Role`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role) from the aforementioned [`Guild`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild), and finally, now you can access the [`members`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role?scrollTo=members) property of [`Role`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Role) and filter the members by their status.

---

```js
// Getting the Guild.
const guild = client.guilds.cache.get('GuildID')
// Getting the Role.
const role = guild.roles.cache.get('RoleID')
// Getting the Members in the Role and filtering them by the status. (Making sure their status is anything other than 'offline' (e.g: idle, do not disturb (dnd), online))
const members = role.members.filter(member => member.presence.status !== 'offline')

console.log(`There are ${members.size} online members with the role ${role.name}.`)
```

---

If your bot sees 0 online members despite there being more, make sure you have the `PRESENCE INTENT` enabled, as seen in the screenshot below:

[image]